# How to write a before filter that instantiates a variable containing a link to the index action of any given controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have many controllers where I want to set up a variable @top_tier_link that has the link to the index action of those controllers. Right now I have it like this:

```
class School::CoursesController < ApplicationController  
  before_filter :set_top_tier_link

  private
    def set_top_tier_link
      @top_tier_link = school_courses_path
    end
end

class School::UsersController < ApplicationController  
  before_filter :set_top_tier_link

  private
    def set_top_tier_link
      @top_tier_link = school_users_path
    end
end
```

I would like to define one before filter that can set that up automatically for any controller. How could I achieve that?

Edit:

This is just a sample, the number of controllers needing this kind of helper is much bigger.  This variable is used at the layout level, so most controllers need this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define it in the ApplicationController. There you can differenciate based on the `params[:controller]` variable. Something like this:

```
before_filter :set_top_tier_link

def set_top_tier_link
  case params[:controller]
    when 'Courses'; @top_tier_link = school_courses_path
    when 'Users'; @top_tier_link = school_users_path
  end
end
```

Or even better to specify a helper for that, which does almost the same. Like this:

```
def top_tier_link
  @top_tier_link ||= case params[:controller]
    when 'Courses'; school_courses_path
    when 'Users'; school_users_path
  end
end

helper_method :top_tier_link
```

UPDATE: The path names can be generated automatically if you do not want to hardcode. A bit dangerous, but it should do the work:

```
def top_tier_link
  @top_tier_link ||= send(params[:controller].gsub("/","_")+"_path")
end
```

Comment: Close, but not exactly what I am looking for. The thing is there are more than 2 controllers. The number could be 30+. So I am looking for a dynamic solution where I don't need to hardcode links.

Comment: You can generate it dinamically. The path names are dinamically created, you can mimic them. Check the update.

Comment: undefined method `school/courses_path' for #<School::CoursesController:0x007fb7cc9c7d78>

Comment: I'm not using namespaces, hence the difference. Just replace the slash with an underscore and it will be okay. Updated the answer.